# My project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, but the suggested fix doesn't work

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies

so I just upgraded flutter and quickly got this error:

```
┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │
│ update C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\Swiper\Swiper-main\android\build.gradle:                  │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is a [known breaking change](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version) when upgrading.

**I applied the suggested fix but the error doesn't go away**

Here is my \android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' //there was nothing here before
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
(...)
```

Things I tried:

-flutter clean

-Restart VS Code

-Turn off and cold boot emulator again.

-Looking at similar threads

-Adding implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10" to my app/build.gradle

-Open /android in Android Studio and trying to Gradle Sync (Gradle sync failed: Sync failed:
reason unknown (1 m 26 s 622 ms))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    
    }
```

and go android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties file
change zip file version

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

[change the kotlin version in build.gradle from XXX to 1.6.10 or to newer version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1dEn.png)

[build.gradle>gradle>android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMvcO.png)

Comment: It's better to prefer textual answers over screenshots. The reason is allowed copy-paste and confidence the link will not become invalid in future.